# Adding Additional Text into Existing Placeholder Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, placeholder

I have an input field with an existing place holder

```
<input type="text" name="property_price" id="property_price" placeholder="Monthly Rent" />
```

Now I have an ajax function returning currency (Rs. or USD) based on a country select box above on the form.  I want to add this ajax currency return into the exiting placeholder so final result will look like this in the placeholders

Monthly Rent (Rs.) or
Monthly Rent (USD)

This should be inside the place holder.  The value "Monthly Rent" is also coming from a jquery function which says "Monthly Rent" or "Selling Price" depending on whether the item is for rent or sale.

The ajax funciton currency is returning the result as per below

```
alert(msg);
```

The value of initial placeholder is coming from this Jquery function.

```
$('#property_availablefor').on('change', function() {

        if ( this.value == 'Rent')
        {
        $("#property_price").attr('placeholder', "Monthly Rent");

        }
        else if ( this.value == 'Sale')
        {
        $("#property_price").attr('placeholder', "Total Price");



        }
```

Answer (score 1):

alter the html like:

```
<input type="text" name="property_price" id="property_price" currency="USD" />
```

Set this globaly

```
 var arr = {'Rent':"Monthly Rent",'Sale':"Total Price"};
```

Set the currency type in a data attribute on ajax success & update the placeholder if you change the country after the rent/sale element

```
$('#property_price').attr('currency',currency);
if(  $('#property_availablefor').val().length > 0 ) {//check if the rent/sale element was  selected
     $("#property_price").attr('placeholder', $('#property_availablefor').val()+' '+ currency);
}
```

you change event will look like:

```
$('#property_availablefor').on('change', function() {
     var currency = $('#property_price').attr('currency');
        $("#property_price").attr('placeholder', arr[this.value]+' '+ currency);
});
```

Comment: This would work normally but you see (i have edited the code) my initial placeholder value is also coming from a jquery function.  I should have added that code before.

Comment: this does not seem to be working, i tried fiddling with it also, maybe i am missing something.

Comment: any console  errors, what do you mean by not working?

Comment: ok let me check again jsfiddle is showing exactly what i want

Comment: in my code if i select rent and then country nothing happens, but if i select country and then rent it works... my rent/sale field is above the country field

Comment: you will need to update the placeholder if you change the country after rent/sale element is selected

Answer (score 0):

```
you can do the following:
$(document).on('change', '<country select box>', function() {
//your ajax call that returns the currency
//get the currency value in a variable say 'currencyVal'
//now assign the placeholder to the textbox.
var intitialPlaceholderTxt = $("#property_price").attr('placeholder').substring(0, $("#property_price").attr('placeholder').indexOf('(') != -1 ? $("#property_price").attr('placeholder').indexOf('(') : $("#property_price").attr('placeholder').length);
$("#property_price").attr('placeholder', intitialPlaceholderTxt + ' (' + currencyVal + ')');
});
```

Comment: with you code, there are two things, 1. i need a space between total price and currency (i am from php background so pls help me with this small thing. 2. if you press the country option again it will keep adding more and more currencies....